# How to make .sqliterc commands be quiet

Tags: sqlite

The **.sqliterc** file for sqlite3 is advised primarily for **.this** and **.that** -style dot-commands, like the ever-popular mysql output emulation:

```
.header on
.timer on
.mode column
```

However, you can put whatever SQL you want into .sqliterc.  Once you realize how slow **sqlite3** is, by default, when working with large data sets, you learn some **PRAGMA** commands which make life much better, like `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;`.

Those commands can also go in your .sqliterc, IF you understand those will then affect everything you do with the command-line "sqlite3" tool, regardless of which database!  In my case, that is fine.  For the Linux account I'm using, on a particular machine, I DO want some of those PRAGMA settings *all the time*.

However, some PRAGMA settings produce confirmation output, like `yes` or `off` or `exclusive` or `memory`.  That becomes a problem when you do things like this, and those extra little words of output get silently included:

```
echo "select * from blah;" | sqlite3 foo.db > output.txt
echo "select * from blah;" | sqlite3 foo.db | wc -l
```

If you happen to have 5 PRAGMA statements in .sqliterc, and 2 of them produce output, your line count in that second example (`wc -l`) will be off by two, and your data in `output.txt` is not quite what you expect it to be.  Those extra 2 lines go to `stdout`, not `stderr`, by the way.

To elaborate, with a **.sqliterc** file containing this:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;
PRAGMA cache_size = -500000;
```

Everything works great, but you will get SELECT output like this:

```
off
memory
2904|wan|1417737600|772|108243|0|1946|635589|0
2904|wan|1417737900|765|119478|0|1980|647472|0
2904|wan|1417738200|708|90934|0|1924|622615|0
2904|wan|1417738500|710|105128|0|1914|622634|0
```

Instead of what you want like this:

```
2904|wan|1417737600|772|108243|0|1946|635589|0
2904|wan|1417737900|765|119478|0|1980|647472|0
2904|wan|1417738200|708|90934|0|1924|622615|0
2904|wan|1417738500|710|105128|0|1914|622634|0
```

See the difference?  The question is: Can we somehow make **.sqliterc** commands shut up, and quit printing the result of certain **PRAGMA** commands which pollute our `stdout`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is yes!  This is the best way I found, at least.

***Warning!  This is a bit hackish, and hides some of the reminder "warnings" you might see if you do the non-recommended practice of putting PRAGMA commands in .sqliterc, in the first place!***

Sidebar: When researching this, you might get mislead by `.echo on` and `.echo off` but that doesn't do what we want.  Echo is OFF by default, and that's fine.  The `.echo` setting is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer: Use the `.output` setting.  Set `/dev/null` as the output for all commands, and then set the output back to the default `stdout` at the end.  (Or use `/tmp/somefile` or whatever you want, if you want some record of what you junked.)

Fixed `.sqliterc` file:

```
.output /dev/null
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;
PRAGMA cache_size = -500000;
.output stdout
```

Now you can wrap as many `.dot` and `PRAGMA` commands as you want inside that output "wrapper", and you will never be bothered by their uncontrollable verbosity!

P.S. As a bonus, you now have my recommended 5 performance PRAGMA lines for using sqlite3, with props to [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) . (Mine has a 500 MB cache size; season to taste.)

Comment: You could also use `.output stderr` instead of `.output /dev/null` and then your stdout-redirected files would be correct, and you would still see the 2 lines of garbage, er, I mean, important status results.  Or you could redirect stderr as usual with `2>/dev/null`. **Oops, no you can't!  That doesn't work as expected.  Sqlite3 feature request!?:**

Answer (score 5):

```
sqlite3 -batch
```

quietens things down

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove the PRAGMA outputs as the question was requesting...

input: `sqlite3 ':memory:' -batch 'PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;'`
output: `off`